# java.util.Iterator java.lang.Iterable.iterator () 'on a null object reference I need help to understand

Tags: kotlin, rx-java

I am getting some null values ​​on my list. I don't know what to do I'm in it all day

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

```
class Testando : ArrayList<Testando>() {

     class TestandoItem(
        @SerializedName("complementos")
        val complementos: List<Complemento?>,
        @SerializedName("pratos")
        val pratos: List<Prato?>,
        @SerializedName("post_type")
        val post_type : Int = 0
    )

     class Complemento(
        @SerializedName("COMPLEMENTO_DESCRICAO")
        val cOMPLEMENTODESCRICAO: String,
        @SerializedName("COMPLEMENTO_VALOR")
        val cOMPLEMENTOVALOR: Double,
        @SerializedName("IDITENS_COMPLEMENTO")
        val iDITENSCOMPLEMENTO: Int,
        @SerializedName("ITENS_IDCOMPLEMENTO")
        val iTENSIDCOMPLEMENTO: Int,
        @SerializedName("ITENS_IDPEDIDOS")
        val iTENSIDPEDIDOS: Int
    )

     class Prato(
        @SerializedName("DESCRICAO_PRODUTO")
        val dESCRICAOPRODUTO: String,
        @SerializedName("IDITENS_VENDA")
        val iDITENSVENDA: Int,
        @SerializedName("ITENS_VENDA_QUANTIDADE")
        val iTENSVENDAQUANTIDADE: Int,
        @SerializedName("PRECOVENDA_PRODUTO")
        val pRECOVENDAPRODUTO: Double,
        @SerializedName("VENDAS_VALOR_VENDA")
        val vENDASVALORVENDA: Double
    )
}
```

My Json

```
[
    {
        "pratos": [
            {
                "IDITENS_VENDA": 628,
                "DESCRICAO_PRODUTO": "X BAICON",
                "ITENS_VENDA_QUANTIDADE": 1,
                "PRECOVENDA_PRODUTO": 14.5,
                "VENDAS_VALOR_VENDA": 32
            },
            {
                "IDITENS_VENDA": 629,
                "DESCRICAO_PRODUTO": "X SALADA",
                "ITENS_VENDA_QUANTIDADE": 1,
                "PRECOVENDA_PRODUTO": 10,
                "VENDAS_VALOR_VENDA": 32
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "complementos": [
            {
                "IDITENS_COMPLEMENTO": 670,
                "ITENS_IDPEDIDOS": 619,
                "ITENS_IDCOMPLEMENTO": 6,
                "COMPLEMENTO_DESCRICAO": "BACON",
                "COMPLEMENTO_VALOR": 3.5
            },
            {
                "IDITENS_COMPLEMENTO": 671,
                "ITENS_IDPEDIDOS": 619,
                "ITENS_IDCOMPLEMENTO": 7,
                "COMPLEMENTO_DESCRICAO": "OVO",
                "COMPLEMENTO_VALOR": 1.5
            },
            {
                "IDITENS_COMPLEMENTO": 672,
                "ITENS_IDPEDIDOS": 619,
                "ITENS_IDCOMPLEMENTO": 11,
                "COMPLEMENTO_DESCRICAO": "COM FAROFA",
                "COMPLEMENTO_VALOR": 2.5
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

image 2 values [Result Api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yvyfp.png)

message error [message error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjOJl.png)

**I believe the problem is as follows. The item 0 prato has a null complemento and this is causing the error. And item 1 complemento has item prato null.**

Comment: Please take the information from the two links you provide and put it right in your question.  Providing links is highly discouraged.  It should only be done for things that aren't text.  To have the best chance of getting an answer to your question, you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so someone can easily reproduce the problem you're having.  What you've supplied has no `main` function, and so can't be a MCVE.  We need to be able to easily reproduce the problem ourselves from what you provide.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any error here, code works as it should. You have 2 json objects, one with `Prato` and the second one is `Complemento`. If you want to get rid of nulls then initialize your vals with `emptyList`:

```
    data class TestandoItem(
        @SerializedName("complementos")
        val complementos: List<Complemento?> = emptyList(),
        @SerializedName("pratos")
        val pratos: List<Prato?> = emptyList(),
        @SerializedName("post_type")
        val post_type : Int = 0
    )
```

This is output of parsed json:

```
[TestandoItem(complementos=[]/* no null here*/, 
   pratos=[Prato(dESCRICAOPRODUTO=X BAICON, iDITENSVENDA=628, iTENSVENDAQUANTIDADE=1, pRECOVENDAPRODUTO=14.5, vENDASVALORVENDA=32.0), Prato(dESCRICAOPRODUTO=X SALADA, iDITENSVENDA=629, iTENSVENDAQUANTIDADE=1, pRECOVENDAPRODUTO=10.0, vENDASVALORVENDA=32.0)], post_type=0), 
   TestandoItem(complementos=[Complemento(cOMPLEMENTODESCRICAO=BACON, cOMPLEMENTOVALOR=3.5, iDITENSCOMPLEMENTO=670, iTENSIDCOMPLEMENTO=6, iTENSIDPEDIDOS=619), Complemento(cOMPLEMENTODESCRICAO=OVO, cOMPLEMENTOVALOR=1.5, iDITENSCOMPLEMENTO=671, iTENSIDCOMPLEMENTO=7, iTENSIDPEDIDOS=619), 
   Complemento(cOMPLEMENTODESCRICAO=COM FAROFA, cOMPLEMENTOVALOR=2.5, 
   DITENSCOMPLEMENTO=672, iTENSIDCOMPLEMENTO=11, iTENSIDPEDIDOS=619)], 
   pratos=[]/* and here*/, post_type=0)]
```

If you want to have `Prato` and `Complemento` in same object,  then you should edit your json:

```
[
    {
        "pratos": [
            {
                "IDITENS_VENDA": 628,
                "DESCRICAO_PRODUTO": "X BAICON",
                "ITENS_VENDA_QUANTIDADE": 1,
                "PRECOVENDA_PRODUTO": 14.5,
                "VENDAS_VALOR_VENDA": 32
            },
            {
                "IDITENS_VENDA": 629,
                "DESCRICAO_PRODUTO": "X SALADA",
                "ITENS_VENDA_QUANTIDADE": 1,
                "PRECOVENDA_PRODUTO": 10,
                "VENDAS_VALOR_VENDA": 32
            }
        ]
    //} remove this
       ,
    //{ and this
        "complementos": [
            {
                "IDITENS_COMPLEMENTO": 670,
                "ITENS_IDPEDIDOS": 619,
                "ITENS_IDCOMPLEMENTO": 6,
                "COMPLEMENTO_DESCRICAO": "BACON",
                "COMPLEMENTO_VALOR": 3.5
            },
            {
                "IDITENS_COMPLEMENTO": 671,
                "ITENS_IDPEDIDOS": 619,
                "ITENS_IDCOMPLEMENTO": 7,
                "COMPLEMENTO_DESCRICAO": "OVO",
                "COMPLEMENTO_VALOR": 1.5
            },
            {
                "IDITENS_COMPLEMENTO": 672,
                "ITENS_IDPEDIDOS": 619,
                "ITENS_IDCOMPLEMENTO": 11,
                "COMPLEMENTO_DESCRICAO": "COM FAROFA",
                "COMPLEMENTO_VALOR": 2.5
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

And the output of parsed json:

```
[TestandoItem(complementos=[Complemento(cOMPLEMENTODESCRICAO=BACON, cOMPLEMENTOVALOR=3.5, iDITENSCOMPLEMENTO=670, iTENSIDCOMPLEMENTO=6, iTENSIDPEDIDOS=619), Complemento(cOMPLEMENTODESCRICAO=OVO, cOMPLEMENTOVALOR=1.5, iDITENSCOMPLEMENTO=671, iTENSIDCOMPLEMENTO=7, iTENSIDPEDIDOS=619), Complemento(cOMPLEMENTODESCRICAO=COM FAROFA, cOMPLEMENTOVALOR=2.5, iDITENSCOMPLEMENTO=672, iTENSIDCOMPLEMENTO=11, iTENSIDPEDIDOS=619)], pratos=[Prato(dESCRICAOPRODUTO=X BAICON, iDITENSVENDA=628, iTENSVENDAQUANTIDADE=1, pRECOVENDAPRODUTO=14.5, vENDASVALORVENDA=32.0), Prato(dESCRICAOPRODUTO=X SALADA, iDITENSVENDA=629, iTENSVENDAQUANTIDADE=1, pRECOVENDAPRODUTO=10.0, vENDASVALORVENDA=32.0)], post_type=0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you so much guys now just take it off but one of my doubts. I'm putting Full code. I'm trying to bring the values ​​from the list to a RecycleView and I'm only bringing 1.

**My Adapter**

```
package com.example.restaurant.Adapter

import Testando
import android.content.Context
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.restaurant.Listas.id_complemento
import com.example.restaurant.R
import com.example.restaurant.data.Dat_Complemento
import com.example.restaurant.data.Dat_Itens_Mesa
import com.example.restaurant.data.Dat_PratosItem
import com.example.restaurant.data.Testando2
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.exemplo.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.exemplo.view.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.itens__mesa_pratos.view.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.itens_mesa_complemento.view.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.lista_itens_mesa_complemento.view.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.lista_mesas.view.*
import java.text.NumberFormat
import java.util.*

class Itens_Mesa_Complemento_Adapter( var itens_Comp : List<Testando.TestandoItem>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<Itens_Mesa_Complemento_Adapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.itens__mesa_pratos,parent,false)
        return Itens_Mesa_Complemento_Adapter.ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return itens_Comp.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val itens = itens_Comp[position]

        itens.complementos.forEach {
            println(" Complementos " + it?.cOMPLEMENTODESCRICAO)
            holder.complemento.setText(it?.cOMPLEMENTODESCRICAO.toString())
        }

    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val complemento = itemView.TextViewPedidoName
    }
}
```

**I get the result in println but in recycleview it only brings 1 value**
result println

```
> I/System.out:  Complementos COM FEIJOADA
>      Complementos COM FEIJOADA I/System.out:  Complementos BACON
>      Complementos BACON
```

**call Adapter**

```
package com.example.restaurant.Listas

import Testando
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.*
import com.example.restaurant.Adapter.Itens_Mesa_Adapter
import com.example.restaurant.Adapter.Itens_Mesa_Complemento_Adapter
import com.example.restaurant.Adapter.idmesas
import com.example.restaurant.Api
import com.example.restaurant.Dao.AppBancoDados
import com.example.restaurant.R
import com.example.restaurant.data.Dat_Complemento
import com.example.restaurant.data.Dat_Pedidos
import com.example.restaurant.data.Dat_PratosItem
import com.example.restaurant.data.Testando2
import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers
import io.reactivex.disposables.Disposable
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.exemplo.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.lista__itens__mesa_pratos.*
import java.util.*
import kotlin.collections.ArrayList


class Lista_Itens_Mesa : AppCompatActivity() {

    val client by lazy {
        Api.create()
    }
    var disposable: Disposable? = null


    private lateinit var recycleview: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var viewadapter1: RecyclerView.Adapter<*>
    private lateinit var viewManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager

    //    private lateinit var adapter: ConcatAdapter
    private lateinit var db: AppBancoDados

    var dt_pratos = ArrayList<Dat_PratosItem>()
    var dtcomplementos = ArrayList<Dat_Complemento>()
    var dt_pedidos = ArrayList<Dat_Pedidos>()


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.lista__itens__mesa_pratos)  //lista__itens__mesa_pratos
        val numbercolumns = 1
        recyclerViewItens_Mesa.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerViewItens_Mesa.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(this, OrientationHelper.HORIZONTAL))
        BuscarTestando()

    }

    fun Buscar_Itens_Complementos() {
        disposable = client.Lista_Pratos_Complementos(idmesas)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                { result ->

                    result.forEach {
                        dtcomplementos.add(it)
                        //   val adaptador = Itens_Mesa_Adapter(dt_pratos)
                        //  adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged()
                        //   exemploreciclo.adapter = adaptador
                    }
                },
                { error ->
                    println(" Erro não esperado! " + error.printStackTrace())
                })
    }
    fun Buscar_Itens_Pratos() {
        disposable = client.Lista_Pratos(idmesas)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                { result ->


                    result.forEach {
                        dt_pratos.add(it)
//                        val adaptador = Itens_Mesa_Adapter(dt_pratos)
                        //   adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged()
                        //  exemploreciclo.adapter = adaptador
                    }
                },
                { error ->
                    println(" Erro não esperado! " + error.printStackTrace())
                })
    }
    fun LoadData(){

        dt_pratos.forEach {
            println(" Testando " + it.nOMEPRODUTO)
        }
    }


    fun BuscarTestando(){
        disposable = client.Testando(idmesas)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                { result ->

                    viewadapter1 = Itens_Mesa_Complemento_Adapter(result)
                    recyclerViewItens_Mesa.adapter = viewadapter1

                },
                { error ->
                    println(" Erro não esperado! " + error.printStackTrace())
                })
    }
}
```

**what would i be doing wrong ?**